# How do I update a Fragment in a TabLayout with new data?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I am creating an application with 3 tabs. I have taken the code for a notepad-like app from [here](http://www.parallelcodes.com/creating-a-notepad-application-in-android/), and what I want is to put the notepad in a fragment inside a tab. I have done this but whenever I add a new note it is not reflected in the tab. I think I will have to use `notifyDataSetChanged()` but I am having difficulty as to where I can use it. Some help will be appreciated.

I have put a FAB in the tab. When I click it the app goes to the `DisplayNote` where I can enter the note title and content for the note as in the original app. I have confirmed that when I click "Save" the note is saved but the tab does not show this.

This is the relevant code for my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
  }
}
```

This is the code for the Adapter:

```
class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new Tab1();
        case 1:
            return new Tab2();
        case 2:
            return new Tab3();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Show 3 total pages.
    return 3;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Tab 1";
        case 1:
            return "Tab 2";
        case 2:
            return "Notes";
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

And this is the code for the third tab:

```
public class Tab3Notes extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mynotes, container, false);
    FloatingActionButton add_note;
    add_note = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.add_note_button);
    add_note.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putInt("id", 0);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), DisplayNote.class);
            intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
  }
}
```

Comment: The `add_note` button will eventually display a `DisplayNote` activity. Could you post the code of the `DisplayNote` activity? How does this activity relate to the `SectionsPagerAdapter` that you already have? My guess is the `notifyDatasetChange()` will need to be placed in the `DisplayNote` - e.g. when user decides to add a new note.

Comment: @DatNguyen the code is available in the link I have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your SectionsPagerAdapter:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

Then when you call `notifyDatasetChanged`, the adapter will think all the pages are new and recreate them

Comment: The thing is, I do not know _where_ exactly is it that I should be using `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: After you've updated the list that is used to populate your fragments.